# JScrollPane. Отключение скролла

Tags: java, swing, прокрутка

У меня есть основное окно с JPanel. На эту панель добавляются панели с JTextArea и JRadioButton (в коде) динамического размера. JTextArea обёрнуты в JScrollPane (хоть он и не используется, т.к. размер динамический) для того, чтобы основное окно отрисовывало панели с начала (если не оборачивать в скроллпейн, основное окно прокручивается до конца).

Проблема в том, что скролл основной панели не работает когда курсор находится над JTextArea. Как заставить его работать (setEnabled(false), отключение скролла через политики не помогает)?

**UPD.**

```
public class Test1Frame extends JFrame {
private JPanel test1Panel = new JPanel();
private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(test1Panel);

public Test1Frame(String title) {
    super(title);
    test1Panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(test1Panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    test1Panel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(20);
    setSize(800, 600);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    runTest1();
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test1Frame("sdsdv");
}

private void runTest1() {
    List<String> testQuestions = Arrays.asList(
            "test", "test", "sdvsdvsv", "dvsdvsdvsdv", "sdvasdvasddv", "sdvasdvasddv", "sdvasdvasddv",
            "sdvasdvasddv", "sdvasdvasddv", "sdvasdvasddv", "sdvasdvasddv", "asdvasdvasddv",
            "sdvasdvasddv", "sdvasdvasddv", "sdvasdvasddv", "sdvasdvasddv", "asdvasdvasddv");
    for (String question : testQuestions) {
        test1Panel.add(new RadioPanel(question));
    }
}

private class RadioPanel extends JPanel {
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JRadioButton radioButtonYes;
    private JRadioButton radioButtonNo;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    private RadioPanel(String text) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        textArea = new JTextArea(text);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        JPanel panelRadio = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(panelRadio, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        panelRadio.setLayout(boxLayout);
        panelRadio.setAlignmentX(JPanel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        radioButtonYes = new JRadioButton("Да", false);
        radioButtonNo = new JRadioButton("Нет", false);
        panelRadio.add(radioButtonYes);
        panelRadio.add(radioButtonNo);
        ButtonGroup butGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        butGroup.add(radioButtonYes);
        butGroup.add(radioButtonNo);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panelRadio, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Не совсем понятно для чего вы используете JTextArea, может стоит присмотреться к другому компоненту? Приведите пример кода, который бы позволил скопировать его и запустить для теста.

Comment: JLabel не переносит текст на новую строку. Сейчас переделаю код.

Comment: Код исправил. Теперь можно запустить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рассмотрите все же такой вариант:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.UUID;

    public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
        private JPanel test1Panel = new JPanel();
        private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(test1Panel);

        public TestFrame(String title) {
            super(title);
            test1Panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(test1Panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            test1Panel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
            scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(20);
            setSize(800, 600);
            setResizable(false);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
            runTest1();
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new TestFrame("sdsdv");
        }

        private void runTest1() {
            List<String> testQuestions = Arrays.asList(generateText());
            for (String question : testQuestions) {
    //            String finalQuestion = "<html><body style=\"background-color:white;\">" + question.replace("\n", "<br>") + "</body>";
                String finalQuestion = "<html>" + question.replace("\n", "<br>");
                test1Panel.add(new RadioPanel(finalQuestion));
            }
        }

        private class RadioPanel extends JPanel {
            private JLabel textLabel;
            private JRadioButton radioButtonYes;
            private JRadioButton radioButtonNo;

            private RadioPanel(String text) {
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                textLabel = new JLabel(text);
                JPanel panelRadio = new JPanel();
                BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(panelRadio, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
                panelRadio.setLayout(boxLayout);
                panelRadio.setAlignmentX(JPanel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
                radioButtonYes = new JRadioButton("Да", false);
                radioButtonNo = new JRadioButton("Нет", false);
                panelRadio.add(radioButtonYes);
                panelRadio.add(radioButtonNo);
                ButtonGroup butGroup = new ButtonGroup();
                butGroup.add(radioButtonYes);
                butGroup.add(radioButtonNo);
                add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                add(panelRadio, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                textLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                textLabel.setBorder(
                        BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5),
                                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY)
                        )
                );
                setBorder(
                        BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5),
                                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY)
                        )
                );
            }
        }

        public String[] generateText() {
            int randomBlocks = new Random().nextInt(10) + 10;
            String[] array = new String[randomBlocks];
            for (int i = 0; i < randomBlocks; i++) {
                int randomRows = new Random().nextInt(10) + 10;
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int r = 0; r < randomRows; r++) {
                    int randomChar = new Random().nextInt(30) + 10;
                    for (int ch = 0; ch < randomChar; ch++) {
                        stringBuilder.append(UUID.randomUUID());
                    }
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                }
                array[i] = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            return array;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А как ограничить ширину блока, оставив высоту динамической?

Comment: А, и реализовать перенос слова на новую строку? Проще написать метод обработки, или есть что-то готовое?